# Why should I not implement Equals and GetHashCode using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have some objects with a bunch of fields and I find myself having to implement GetHashCode and Equals.  It is painful to go though each field manually so I wrote them like this:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = 17;
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        hash = hash * 23 + p.GetValue(this, null).GetHashCode();
    }
    return hash;
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (p.GetValue(obj, null) != p.GetValue(this, null))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Other than speed considerations why shouldn't I implement them like this?

Comment: Apart from speed issues, note that not all correct implementations of `GetHashCode` and `Equals` are equivalent to the above algo. Btw, there are several issues with the posted code. You could dereference `null` in multiple places. Additionally, your version of `Equals` uses reference equality between corresponding properties, which is not the most common idiom.

Comment: Use ReSharper -- it'll generate correct implementations of `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for you.

Comment: Another bug - you're checking the properties of this.GetType(), so inheritence equivalence can introduce odd behavior (eg, `aManager.Equals(anEmployee)` will test different properties than `anEmployee.Equals(aManager)`).  Also, what happens when you do `anApple.Equals(anOrange)`?  I haven't tested, but seems like you'll have some odd behavior when calling Equals using unrelated types.

Comment: There is a non-prime number in the hash caclulation. I assume you meant to use 33. :-)

Comment: @Christian - think you meant 31 as 33 isn't prime either :)

Comment: @Christian I actually meant 23, 33 isn't prime either.

Comment: Oops, that'll teach me to think before commenting :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are a few reasons I would avoid this route

- It's much more reliable to compare fields instead of properties
- Your code makes the incorrect assumption that two objects are considered to be equal if they are the same reference (you are using ==).  This is not the case as many types implement value equality via `.Equals`.  It is very possible and legal for two different references to be considered `Equals` and would beat your test.
- If this form of Equality is used in a wide spread manner through your code base it will very easily lead to infinite recursion when the object graph has cycles.
- The `GetHashCode` method ignores that a property could be `null`

Below is a concrete example of a type which would cause infinite recursion in your application

```
class C1 {
  public object Prop1 { get; set; }
};

var local = new C1();
local.Prop1 = local;
var x = local.GetHashCode();  // Infinite recursion
```

Answer (score 5):

Any value-type properties will be boxed by the `GetValue` calls, which means that they'll never compare as equal even if they have the same value.

You can avoid this by calling the static [`Equals(x,y)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) method -- which will then defer to the virtual [`x.Equals(y)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) method if necessary -- rather than using the non-virtual `==` operator, which will always test reference equality in this case.

```
if (!object.Equals(p.GetValue(obj, null), p.GetValue(this, null)))
    return false;
```

Comment: Typo fixed, but != left to keep your answer valid

Comment: `a.Equals(b)` will throw if `a` is `null`; `Object.Equals(a, b)` will return `false`.

Answer (score 2):

1. It may give a poorly conditioned hash (not all properties are equal in determining object identity.)
2. As currently implemented, the hash computation may overflow.

Answer (score 2):

If your object is equal *only* if all properties are equal then go ahead. But I doubt it. E.g an employee is unique by it's employee Id. You will not be able to compare changes in employee data if you do this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are speaking of implementing not only `Equals` but also `GetHashCode` this means that what you have in your hands is immutable `struct`s or `class`es.

You are probably also aware of the fact that reflection is a bit slower than manually written code, and you know that your case falls squarely into the general 95% of cases where performance is not a concern.

In this case, you definitely ***should*** implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` using reflection.

That's because:

- it will save you from writing copious amounts of silly repetitive code, ***and***
- it is guaranteed to handle all fields, whereas manually written code might inadvertently omit some field, causing a very insidious bug.

However, it is tricky.

Here is how to do it in a way that actually works.

Look at the "PEARL" comments in the code to see why it is tricky.

Note: You can do the hash-code calculation by yourself, but I am using `System.HashCode` for convenience. To make this convenience available to you, use NuGet to add a reference to package `Microsoft.Bcl.HashCode`.

class `ReflectionHelpers`

```
#nullable enable
using Sys = System;
using SysReflect = System.Reflection;

public static bool MemberwiseEquals<T>( T a, object? b ) where T : notnull
{
    if( b == null )
        return false;
    if( ReferenceEquals( a, b ) )
        return true;
    Sys.Type type = typeof(T);
    Assert( a.GetType() == type );
    Assert( b.GetType() == type );
    foreach( SysReflect.FieldInfo fieldInfo in type.GetFields( //
            SysReflect.BindingFlags.Instance | //
            SysReflect.BindingFlags.Public | //
            SysReflect.BindingFlags.NonPublic ) )
    {
        object? value1 = fieldInfo.GetValue( a );
        object? value2 = fieldInfo.GetValue( b );
        if( fieldInfo.FieldType.IsPrimitive )
        {
            if( !value1.Equals( value2 ) )
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if( !DotNetHelpers.Equals( value1, value2 ) )
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static int MemberwiseGetHashCode<T>( T obj ) where T : notnull
{
    Sys.Type type = typeof(T);
    Assert( obj.GetType() == type );
    Sys.HashCode hashCodeBuilder = new Sys.HashCode();
    foreach( SysReflect.FieldInfo fieldInfo in type.GetFields( //
            SysReflect.BindingFlags.Instance | //
            SysReflect.BindingFlags.Public | //
            SysReflect.BindingFlags.NonPublic ) )
    {
        Assert( fieldInfo.IsInitOnly );
        object? fieldValue = fieldInfo.GetValue( obj );
        hashCodeBuilder.Add( fieldValue );
    }
    return hashCodeBuilder.ToHashCode();
}
```

class `DotNetHelpers`

```
using Sys = System;
using Legacy = System.Collections;

// PEARL: Arrays in C# implement `IEnumerable` but provide no implementation for `Equals()`!
//        This means that `object.Equals( array1, array2 )` will always return false, even if the arrays have identical contents!
//        This is especially sinister since arrays are often treated as `IEnumerable`, so you may have two instances of `IEnumerable`
//        which yield identical elements and yet the instances fail to return `true` when checked using `object.Equals()`.
//        The standing advice is to use `a.SequenceEqual( b )` to compare `IEnumerable`, which is retarded, due to the following reasons:
//          1. This will only work when you know the exact types of the objects being compared; it might suit application programmers who are perfectly
//             accustomed writing copious amounts of mindless application-specific code to accomplish standard tasks, but it does not work when you are
//             writing framework-level code, which operates on data without needing to know (nor wanting to know) the exact type of the data.
//          2. This will not work when the `IEnumerable`s in turn contain other `IEnumerable`s (or arrays) because guess what `SequenceEqual()` uses
//             internally to compare each pair of elements of the `IEnumerable`s? It uses `object.Equals()`, which miserably fails when comparing
//             instances of `IEnumerable`! Again, this might be fine for application programmers who will happily write thousands of lines of
//             application-specific code to compare application data having intimate knowledge of the structure of the data, but it does not work when
//             writing framework-level code.
//        This method fixes this insanity. It is meant to be used as a replacement for `object.Equals()` under all circumstances.
public new static bool Equals( object? a, object? b )
{
    if( ReferenceEquals( a, b ) )
        return true;
    if( a == null || b == null )
        return false;
    if( a.Equals( b ) )
        return true;
    if( a is Legacy.IEnumerable enumerableA && b is Legacy.IEnumerable enumerableB )
        return legacyEnumerablesEqual( enumerableA, enumerableB );
    return false;

    static bool legacyEnumerablesEqual( Legacy.IEnumerable a, Legacy.IEnumerable b )
    {
        Legacy.IEnumerator enumerator1 = a.GetEnumerator();
        Legacy.IEnumerator enumerator2 = b.GetEnumerator();
        try
        {
            while( enumerator1.MoveNext() )
            {
                if( !enumerator2.MoveNext() )
                    return false;
                if( !Equals( enumerator1.Current, enumerator2.Current ) )
                    return false;
            }
            if( enumerator2.MoveNext() )
                return false;
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            (enumerator1 as Sys.IDisposable)?.Dispose();
            (enumerator2 as Sys.IDisposable)?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Use it as follows:

class `MyClass`

```
public override bool Equals( object other ) => other is MyClass kin && Equals( kin );
public bool Equals( MyClass other ) => ReflectionHelpers.MemberwiseEquals( this, other );
public override int GetHashCode() => ReflectionHelpers.MemberwiseGetHashCode( this );
```